# Unable to set color for spanned string in android

Tags: android

I am trying to put color for Spanned String,But the color is not applying.Its shows same color

as text view color.The code which i wrote.

```
TextView desc2=(TextView)listrow.findViewById(R.id.desc222);
desc2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#811c1d'><b>MyText</b></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;").toString());
```

if i remove "toString()" it throws

```
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:473)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:243)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:61)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:298)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:357)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1387)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:370)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4050)
04-24 06:20:58.750: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
```

Can any one tell me what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
TextView desc2=(TextView)listrow.findViewById(R.id.desc222);
desc2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#811c1d'><b>MyText</b></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpannableString:

```
    SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString("MyText");
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(yourColor);
    spanned.setSpan(fcs, 0, "MyText".length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    yourTextView.setText(spanned);
```